# Need for vuex for 2 components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have just 2 Components at any given point in time 
a global component to store all the common data 
and a child component which changes based on vue-router.

Is there a real need to add vuex complexity in my case.

Comment: With something this simple, there doesn't seem to be any reason to introduce Vuex over standard component state (unless your application is likely to grow). Then again, Vuex isn't very difficult to implement so it won't hurt you too much. That being said, this type of question isn't really on-topic on SO so will likely be closed as "primarily opinion based"

Comment: btw,, how do i refer other components or atleast the parent component

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: events .. that  what i was looking for .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll benefit from Vuex in this case.

You can just use props and custom events.

Comment: yeah .. make sense